# Unable to read a pickle file on GCP storage bucket. Other files are accessible

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a GCP storage bucket where I am trying to access a pickle file from GCP. My other data files are accessible and am able to read them into my notebook.

However, the pickle file is not recognized. Reading up on stack overflow suggests that pickle does not understand what "gs - Google storage" is and as such not able to interpret the path. I have tried workarounds to name the bucket and assign the file to a blob and read it. Those have been unsuccessful as well. Can someone help me if you have seen this problem before?

My code is below:

```
def load_weather_forecast() -> Dict[str, Dict[List[datetime], List[float]]]:
    """Loads the wind data and forecast for three locations and returns it in a form of dictionary.
    """
    from google.cloud import storage
    # Instantiates a client
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket_name = 'acai_testdata'
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob('Climate Change/Wind Power Forecasting/Design/forecasting/work/data/weather_forecast.pkl')
    downloaded_blob = blob.download_as_string()
    #print(downloaded_blob)
    #with open("gs://acai_testdata/Climate Change/Wind Power Forecasting/Design/forecasting/work/data/weather_forecast.pkl", "rb") as f:
    with open(downloaded_blob, "rb") as f:
        weather_forecasts = pickle.load(f)
    return weather_forecasts
```